# Does exists a notion which gives more information about Holder functions?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, definition, brownian-motion, holder-spaces

We know the definition of a $\alpha$-Holder continous function $\;f:I\to\Bbb R$ (where $0<\alpha\le1$ and $I\subseteq\Bbb R$ is an interval): it is a measurable function such that
$$
\sup_{0\le s<t\le1}\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha}}<+\infty.
$$

But, let us consider $\alpha=1/2-\beta\;$ for some $\beta>0\;,\;$$I=[0,1]\;,\;$ $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ and $g(t)$ be a trajectory of the standard Brownian motion.

It's clear that $f$ is *exactly* $\alpha$-Holder, in the sense that the above condition is no longer true if we exceed only a few on $\alpha$: for every $\epsilon>0$
$$
\sup_{0\le s<t\le1}\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha+\epsilon}}=+\infty.
$$

BUT it's important to notice that $x=0$ is the unique patological point: if we cut out the zero by considering $f$ on $[\delta,1]$, we get a $\mathcal C^{\infty}$ function, so now we get that
$$
\sup_{\delta\le s<t\le1}\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha+\epsilon}}<+\infty.
$$

At the same time, things are different for $g$: every point of the trajectories of the BM is patological, in sense that, for every $J\subseteq I$ such that $\operatorname{Acc}_I(J)\neq\emptyset$ (i.e. $J$ has accumulation points in $I$) we have that, taking $\epsilon=\beta$,
$$
\sup_{s<t\\s,t\in J}\frac{|g(t)-g(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha+\beta}}=+\infty.
$$

How can we distinguish these different behaviors of functions which are, equally $\alpha-$Holder continuous? Does exists any suitable definition which highlights the subtle differences of the above functions?

Comment: You can multiply or divide $\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha}}$ by logarithmic factors, such as (I think) $\log \frac{1}{|t-s|}.$ More generally, google [modulus of continuity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22modulus+of+continuity%22).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: thanks for your answer. I can't see how multiply/divide by $\log\frac1{|t-s|}$ can be helpful

Comment: Couldn't you ask this about basically any definition? For instance, let $f(x)=x\sin(\frac1x)$, extended by continuity to $0$, and let $g$ be an everywhere differentiable function with almost everywhere discontinuous derivative. Then both $f$ and $g$ are "equally differentiable" in the sense that both are differentiable but not $C^1$, but the nature of how they each fail to be $C^1$ is vastly different.

Comment: What I meant was using things like $\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha}\cdot \log \frac{1}{|t-s|}}$ or more generally $\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha} \left( \log \frac{1}{|t-s|} \right)^{\beta}}$ for positive values of $\beta.$ Even more generally, see [Hardy's scales of infinity](https://www.google.com/search?q=logarithmic+"scales+of+infinity").